# Upgrade from 4.3.1 to 4.6.9 (Joomla) = fails; DB upgrade freezes

Tags: joomla, upgrade, database

It reports (on DB upgrade screen): "[Executed: Finish Upgrade DB to 4.3.8]"

We let it run for over over an hour; stayed stuck.

A previous attempt got stuck at v.4.4.3.

(This upgrade is being attempted first on a DEV install, too.)

We've read ***many*** forum posts about this issue, here and on CiviCRM.org forums.

There is urgency about this problem (why, of course there is!). We can't/won't attempt the update on the LIVE site until we have confidence—unless someone can authoritatively link this problem to a migrated install, etc.

Thanks in advance for help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

Are you upgrading directly from 4.3.1 to 4.6.9?

If not, it might be worth trying a more incremental upgrade (e.g. 4.3.1 to 4.3.7, then 4.3.7 to 4.3.8 in case there's a sticking point there, then 4.3.8 to 4.3.11, 4.3.11 to 4.4, and so on - it's tedious, but may stop the upgrade from stalling, or give you an error message you can follow up.